# Light Intensity sensor bh1750

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, arduino, sensors

Is there any way to store light intensity data from the bh1750 sensor on firebase and display it using the android app.
I am a beginner any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you would want to get an Ethernet or wireless-connected Arduino, or connect a WiFi adapter to an Arduino, and have it able to connect to the internet.

Then you would need to connect whatever sensor (probably I2C) to your Arduino, and have it read in environment data like temperature, humidity, whatever you want.

With connectivity to the internet, you can send a POST request to Google's Firebase API. But I wouldn't worry about that until you at least have the arduino, internet adapter, and environment sensor.

Firebase apparently has a "REST" http API, https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/
And people have been able to send POST requests via arduino over WiFi https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/50931/how-to-post-http-post-requests-on-my-website
and Ethernet shouldn't be too hard either (it requires a seperate piece of hardware just like the WiFi path does, but there seems to be more popularity among WiFi enthusiats on Arduino than Ethernet enthusiasts.
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet